# How to make a branch in SmartGit with beanstalk?

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, smartgit, beanstalk-svn

I have SmartGit GUI tool for my beanstalk repos. I want to make a branch of one of my repos. For this i have created a branch using smartGit branch manager, but how i create this to beanstalk. and the other question is "What is track-branch" in SmartGit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not currently on your created *branch*, use **Branch|Switch** to switch to your *branch*. Perform **Remote|Push** which will ask you whether to configure tracking, confirm this. After that your *branch* will be pushed to beanstalk. Finally you should see *origin/branch* in the branch manager (assuming that your remote beanstalk repository is the *origin*)

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalk will automatically detect new branches pushed to it once it is established as a remote.

While switched to your new branch, push it to your Beanstalk remote using SmartGit.

You can verify the new branch being successfully pushed by browsing to that repository in Beanstalk and clicking the "Change tree" button:

[image: change tree]

In this view, any remotes and tags that have been pushed to your Beanstalk remote will be presented.